# How to execute a linux shell script from a C# application?

Tags: c#, linux, bash, shell, cygwin

I have a linux shell script which I can execute manually with CygWin terminal in windows.

```
sh E://Work/sync.sh E://Work/Voice/Temp
```

But I'm having some difficulty when I'm trying to run the shell script in my C# application with the same argument.

```
string command = "E://Work/sync.sh E://Work/Voice/Temp";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe", command);
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
Console.WriteLine(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

It's giving me error:

```
E://Work/sync.sh: line 47: rm: command not found
E://Work/sync.sh: line 48: mkdir: command not found
E://Work/sync.sh: line 50: ls: command not found
E://Work/sync.sh: line 59: ls: command not found
E://Work/sync.sh: line 60: rmdir: command not found
```

Then I tried a different approach.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe");
psi.Arguments = "--login -c sh E://Work/sync.sh  E://Work/Voice/Temp";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

This initiates a CygWin command prompt like this:
[image]

Then if I enter my command manually it works.
`E://Work/sync.sh E://Work/Voice/Temp`

How can I execute the script automatically from my application without any manual input?

Comment: try psi.Arguments = "--login -c /cygdrive/e/Work/sync.sh  /cydrive/e/Work/Voice/Temp";

Comment: Doesn't work. Showing error - "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some google search, I found a way to do this. All I had to do is change `"--login -c"` to `"--login -i"`

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe");
psi.Arguments = "--login -i E://Work/sync.sh  E://Work/Voice/Temp";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```